# Problem with refreshing Data c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

My problem is first I'm downladin xml file from server like this:

```
  private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                //pobieranie danych z pliku xml znajdujacego sie na serwerze
                WebClient client = new WebClient();

                client.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
                client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("Myurl/baza.xml"));


            }
private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Error == null)
                {
                    XDocument xdoc3 = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);

                    var data = from query in xdoc3.Descendants("Item")
                               select new Item
                               {
                                   name = (string)query.Element("name"),
                                   prise = (int)query.Element("prise"),
                                   howmany = (int)query.Element("howmany")

                               };

                    items_listBox.ItemsSource = data;
                    status_textBlock.Text = "Data ok";
                }
                else {
                    status_textBlock.Text = "Fail";
                    kup_button.Visibility = 0;
                }
```

Then i'v made a refresh button, and add function to it, basicly the same code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sendera, RoutedEventArgs a)
        {
            WebClient client2 = new WebClient();

            client2.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleteda;
            client2.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(Myurl/baza.xml"));


        }

private void HttpsCompleteda(object sendera, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs a)
        {
            #region server_ok
            if (a.Error == null
            {
                #region refresh

                XDocument xdoca = XDocument.Parse(a.Result, LoadOptions.None);

                var new_data = from query in xdoca.Descendants("Item")
                           select new Item
                           {
                               name = (string)query.Element("name"),
                               prise = (int)query.Element("prise"),
                               howmany = (int)query.Element("howmany")
                           };
                items_listBox.ItemsSource = new_data;
              }
```

After laod first xml, it (xml file) is chenged(i can see via my web browser) but when i refresh it looks steel the same in

```
items_listBox.ItemsSource
```

any ideas? thanks for help
xaml code

```
x:Class="Sklep.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Sklep" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Sklep" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" Height="49" Width="456" FontSize="30" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Button Content="zamow" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,474,0,0" Name="kup_button" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Click="kup_button_Click" />
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,550,0,74" Name="textBlock1" Text="Ilość sztuk" Width="190" />
            <TextBox Height="57" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,536,0,0" Name="order_textBox" Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" TextAlignment="Right" FontSize="18" />
            <CheckBox Content="zapłacone" Height="86" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="171,568,0,0" Name="pay_box" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="261" />
            <ListBox x:Name="items_listBox" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="300" Margin="6,62,6,174" MaxHeight="500">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding prise}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding howmany}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <TextBlock Height="53" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,3,0,0" Name="status_textBlock" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="449" TextAlignment="Center" />
            <Button Content="Odswież" Height="103" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="339,545,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="114" FontSize="15" Click="button1_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: When you step through it in the debugger, what is a.Error?  What is a.Result?

Comment: ther is no error, but how can i find out what is a.Result?

Answer (score 2):

The request will be cached by the WebClient.
The easiest solution is to make the request look like a different one by adding something unique to the query string.

```
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("Myurl/baza.xml?rand=" + Guid.NewGuid()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems more to be a data binding problem than about a web service call. You should give your XAML code.

Comment: There is apparently nothing wrong in your code. Your problem comes from the fact that you cannot debug on the phone. Something wrong happens in your refresh code (not called, returns an error, data binding fails...). Try to create a test in a Silverlight application and debug it in Visual Studio.

Comment: I would create a Silverlight project that calls your web service, put breakpoints and look.

Comment: is this the only way to solve it? Maybe am ending conectios in wrong way, or wathever, i pretty confused and in big hurry

Comment: Even if you're in a hurry, believe me it is not a waste of time to simplify your problem. Start a clean project with just your ListBox and the Refresh Button. The error will be obvious. Nobody here can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it using

```
static public WebClient public_webclient
```